# Why is the same both (5 % 2) and (-5 % 2) in Python

Tags: python-2.7, math

I have guessed 5 % 2 is 1 , -5 % 2 is -1

But, In Python, I get the same result.

I think it's not math problem.

```
>>> -5 % 2 
1  ( I think this should be -1 )
>>>  5 % 2
1

>>> -7 % 6 
5 ( I think this should be -1 )
>>> 7 % 6
1
```

Comment: This is the expected behaviour as modulu division in math most often is defined as 
[n = am + b, 0 <= b < |m|](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why? Because the modulo operator is defined that way in python.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html) states:

> The modulo operator always yields a result with the same sign as its
>   second operand (or zero); *[...]*

And:

> The function `math.fmod()` returns a result whose sign matches the
>   sign of the first argument instead, *[...]* Which approach is more
>   appropriate depends on the application.

Comment: Thank you. But, I have still problem. I understand why is the same result both  5%2 and 5%-2 because of your answer. It's because the result is the same sign with second operend. But Why the result of (-7%6) is 5 ?

Comment: @DanDaniel: Because -12 is a multiple of 6, and -7 is 5 more than -12. In other words, -7 = 6 * (-2) + 5, and 0 <= 5 < |6|. See androidavid's comment.

Comment: For this question, I find "because it is so" not very satisfying. I'll attempt my own answer.

Comment: When I combine Cornelissen's answer and Daulton's one, I can understand the reason. Thank you!

Comment: I think this sentence is a key point to understand this problem. **Which approach is more appropriate depends on the application**

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the `%` operation in at least a couple of different ways. One important point of view is that `m % n` finds the element of Z[n] which is congruent to m, where Z[n] is an algebraic representation of the integers restricted to 0, 1, 2, ..., n, called the ring of integers modulo n. Note that all integers, positive, negative, and 0, are congruent to some element 0, 1, 2, ..., n in Z[n].

This ring (that is, this set plus certain operations on it) has many well-known and useful properties. For that reason, it's often advantageous to try to cast a problem in a form that leads to Z[n], where it may be easier to work. This, ultimately, is the reason the Python `%` was given its definition -- in the end, it has to do with operations in the ring of integers modulo n.

This article about [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) (in particular, the part about integers modulo n) could be a good starting point if you'd like to know more about this topic.

Comment: *This, ultimately, is the reason the Python % was given its definition [...]* If you state that as a fact, I'm afraid you'll have to provide sources.

Comment: Thank you for more detail answer!